# UIAlertView title label strange background color issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

First I show the UIAlertView like this in my view controller (really nothing fancy at all):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you"
                                                        message:@"Successfully saved bookmark"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

But as you can see in the screenshot, the title label is taking the background of my view as its background color:

[image: screenshot of UIAlertView]

I have not even the slightest idea of where this could come from, here is how I style my view controller when it appears:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title = @"Details";

    [self.view styleBackgroundColor];

    [self.saveToBookmarks configureButtonStyle];
    [self.getDirections configureButtonStyle];

    self.name.text = [simoItem name];
    self.relativeLocation.text = [self relativeLocationStringForLocation:[simoItem location]];
    self.address.text = [simoItem address];
    self.type.text = [self buildTypesString];

    [self.name styleMainLabel];
    [self.address styleSubLabel];
    [self.type styleSubLabel];
    [self.relativeLocation styleSubLabel];
}
```

Tried cleaning the project, uninstalling the app from the sim and shaking my computer but nothing has done it so far...

EDIT: added code for `styleMainLabel` on request

```
-(void) styleMainLabel {
    //colors
    UIColor *backgroundColor = [Utilities getBackgoundColorPreference];
    UIColor *textColor = [Utilities getTextColorPreference];
    [self setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    [self setTextColor:textColor];

    //text size styling
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Tiresias PCfont" size:35.0];
    self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
}
```

Comment: can u show the code for styleMainLabel.

Comment: I think problem is here  UIColor *backgroundColor = [Utilities getBackgoundColorPreference];
    UIColor *textColor = [Utilities getTextColorPreference];
    [self setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    [self setTextColor:textColor];please change it to the UIColor colorname

Comment: okay I fixed the problem, this was caused by some CALayer color properties set in accessibility events callbacks. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed the problem, this was cause by some CALayer color properties set in accessibility events callbacks. Here is the code that causes the problem

```
- (void)accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused {
    [super accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused];
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];
    layer.backgroundColor = [[Utilities getFocusedBackgroundColorPreference] CGColor];
}

-(void) accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus {
    [super accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus];
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];
    layer.backgroundColor = [[Utilities getBackgoundColorPreference] CGColor];
}
```

I haven't fixed it yet but turning off accessibility made it disappear. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem in styleMainLabel code. So first check your code and again if you are getting then do it.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you"
                                                        message:@"Successfully saved bookmark"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

UILabel *theTitle = [alert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
   [theTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: thanks but it's not working... I tried setTextColor and seBackgroundColor on theTitle with same results...